# How to select NOT ALL text when user clicks on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to select text **(not all)** when user clicks on it.

```
final EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
field.setText("BlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla");

field.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            field.setSelection(0, 10);
        }
    }
});
```

But text isn't selected. The cursor appears at the point of click.

How can I do this?

**Updated:**

Why simple method setSelection(start, end) in "Hello World" app doesn't work?

Comment: how much text do you want to select?

Comment: @nandsito, I want to select any number of characters, but not all text. In above example I select from 0 to 10 (length of text is more than 10 characters).

Comment: do you care for other gestures, e.g. double tap, long press, fling etc. or there is no problem in getting rid of them?

Comment: @nandsito yes, I do. I want the user to be able to put the cursor and edit any part of the text, but the first click always highlights the amount of text I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found incredible solution. If I set **android:selectAllOnFocus="true"** or programmatically.

And simple snippet code works fine:

```
final EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
field.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            field.setSelection(0, 10);
        }
    }
});
```

But if I remove **android:selectAllOnFocus="true"** or set **false** - everything breaks down.

I don't know why!!